# JQUERY - Tabs - show all div content in date-filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a working JQUERY Tab section on jsfiddle.

When the Page loads, I want the .sortALL to be showing.

How can I make it load with sortALL already displaying? I attached a photo and code below.
This would also require the tabs CSS highlight to be active to make it same color as content.

Thanks for any help.

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/k5g6wcw3/

IMAGE:

[image: tab - data-filter show .sortALL on load]

CODE:

CSS

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;float:left;width:100%;}
#tabs{width:80%;margin:2% 10%;background:#efefef;min-height:250px;}
a{cursor:pointer;display:block;width:20%;background:#ddd;text-align:center;padding:2% 0;text-decoration:none;color:#000;}
a:hover{background:#ccc;color:#000;}
.post{padding:2%;width:96%;}
.highlight {background: #efefef;}
```

JQUERY

```
// Variable
var posts = $('.post');
posts.hide();


// Click function
$( ".sort" ).click(function() { 
    // Get data of category
    var customType = $( this ).data('filter'); // category
    console.log(customType);
    console.log(posts.length); // Length of articles

    posts
        .hide()
        .filter(function () {
        return $(this).data('cat') === customType;
        })
        .show(50);
});

// All
$( "#showAll" ).click(function() {
  $( ".post" ).show(50);
});


// color toggle
$( ".sort" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" ).siblings().removeClass("highlight");
});
```

HTML

```
<!--sort links-->
<div id="tabs">
<a href="#" class="sort" id="showAll" >Show All</a>
<a href="#" class="sort" data-filter=".sortA" >Sort A</a>
<a href="#" class="sort" data-filter=".sortB" >Sort B</a>
<a href="#" class="sort" data-filter=".sortC" >Sort C</a>
<a href="#" class="sort" data-filter=".StateA">State A</a>


<!--A-->
<div data-cat=".sortA" class="post"><h2>Sort this A A A</h2><p>This is all about sort A</p></div>
<!--B-->
<div data-cat=".sortB" class="post"><h2>Sort this B</h2><p>This is all about sort B</p></div>
<!--C-->
<div data-cat=".sortC" class="post"><h2>Sort this C</h2><p>This is all about sort C</p></div>
<!--A-->
<div data-cat=".sortA" class="post"><h2>Sort this A A A</h2><p>This is all about sort A</p></div>
<!--Hopewell-->
<div data-cat=".StateA" class="post"><h2>State A Listings</h2><p>This is all about sorting State A listings</p></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class on **showAll** on page load and fire its click event programmatcially.

You can do it like this:

```
$( "#showAll" ).click(function() {
  $( ".post" ).show(50);
}).addClass("highlight").click();  //<------------- note this .click()
```

Now it will firstly show all when first time page will load.

### UPDATED FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/k5g6wcw3/1/

Comment: that works - simple, thanks. but how is it showing the .sortALL data-filter? It is exactly how I want it, I am just trying to learn. Thanks

Comment: I understand the .addClass, is it the .click()?

Comment: what you mean @AlwaysLearning??

Comment: see my image, the first one shows no data-filter info ( Sort this AAA )
The second image shows all data-filter ( Sort AAA thru State A listings )
what is activating the data-filter jquery to show all (.post) divs?

Comment: `.click()` is triggering the click event of the element programmatically, its like you click on show all, but difference is it is via code not via mouse click

Comment: thanks! i just read about it on jquery. I just wanted to understand.